# How does one take a listbox selection and depending on that selection a second list box is created?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have three list boxes and the first one has a certain number of options. When the user selects an option, the second list box needs to fill depending on previous selection. Here is the code I tried. I am using Python 2.7
updated:

```
import sys
import Tkinter as TK

font = ('Times New Rome', 12, 'Bold')
Template = ''
Entrybox1 = ''
Entrybox2 = ''
Lb1 = ''
Lb2 = ''
Lb3 = ''

class smartstopkiosk_tk(TK.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    
    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        #self.parent.title("Smartstop Kiosk")
        global Entrybox1
        global Entrybox2
        global LocalTemplate
        global Software
        seltext = ""
        software = ('Microsoft', 'Abode', 'SAP', 'Lotus  Notes', 'Jive','Cisco',     'Chrome')
        hardware = ("Computer",  "Charger", " USB Headset", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Webcam")
        microsoft = ("Outlook", "Lync", "Word", "Excel", "PowerPoint", "Visio", "Project", "Publisher")
        adobe = ("Adobe Reader", "Java", "Flash", "Adobe Pro")
        cisco = ('IP Communicator', '')
        wireless = ("MYLOW",  "Corporate", "Visitor", "MYLTW")
        printers  = ("2N", "2S", "3N", "3S", "4N",  "4S",  "5N", "5S")      
        mobile =  ("Blackberry", "iPhone","iPad")
        AD  = ("Unlock", "Reset")
        LocalTemplate = ('User Assistance with Software.', 'User Assistance with       Hardware.', 'Mobile Device Support.',
        'Software Installation Request', 'Hardware Request', 'Wireless Connection',   'Password Reset/Username Unlocked', 
        'Add Printer')

         #creates font types
         font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
         font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')
    
         #Creates Instructions for Users
         stepOne = TK.LabelFrame(self, text=" 1. User Information: ", font = font2)
         stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5,   ipady=5)
         stepTwo = TK.LabelFrame(self, text="2. Select Program or Hardware Problems", font = font2)
         stepTwo.grid(row=3, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
         stepThree = TK.LabelFrame(self, text="Please Enter the Problem or Your Request:", font = font2)
         stepThree.grid(row=6, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
    
         #Creates Label for Users
         Label1 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "First Name", font = font)
         Label1.grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
         Label2 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "Last Name", font = font)
         Label2.grid(column = 4, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
         Label3 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "UserName", font = font)
         Label3.grid(column = 6, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
    
         #Creates Entry Box for User input
         self.entry = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
         self.entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1,padx = (10, 10))
         entry2 = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
         entry2.grid(column = 4, row = 1,padx = (10, 10))
         entry3 = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
         entry3.grid(column = 6, row = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = (10, 10))
    
         #Creates User Input Box
         Usertext = TK.Text(stepThree, height = 10, width = 110, font = font)
         Usertext.grid(column = 2, row = 15, padx = (10, 10))
    
         #Creates List Boxes
         Listbox1 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font   = font, exportselection = 0)
         Listbox1.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
         for i in LocalTemplate:
             Listbox1.insert(TK.END, i)
         Listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.selection)
         Listbox2 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font, exportselection = 0)
         Listbox2.grid(column = 4, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
         for x in seltext:
             Listbox2.insert(TK.END, x)
         Listbox2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.selection)
         Listbox3 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font, exportselection = 0)
         Listbox3.grid(column = 6, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
    
         #Creates Buttons
         Submit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2)
         Submit.grid(column = 3, row = 10, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))
         Startover = TK.Button(self, text = 'Cancel', font = font2)
         Startover.grid(column = 4, row = 10, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))
    
         def selection(self, val):
         sender = val.Listbox1
         index = listbox1.curselection()
         value = Listbox1.get(index[0])
         if index == 1 or index == 4:
             seltext = software
         elif index == 2 or index == 5:
             seltext = hardware
         elif index == 3:
             seltext = mobile
         elif index == 6:
             seltext = wireless
         elif index == 7:
             seltext = AD
         elif index == 8:
             seltext = printer

def main():
    app = smartstopkiosk_tk(None)
    app.geometry("1300x768")

    app.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I keep getting this error Traceback
File "C:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1845, in **getattr**
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: selection

UPDATED!
Here is the how I was able to have text in the first list box and have the second list box fill depending on your choice.

```
    def getchoice(event):
        seltext = ''
        INDEX = Listbox1.curselection()
        if INDEX == (0,) or INDEX == (4,):
            seltext = software
        elif INDEX == (1,) or INDEX == (5,):
            seltext = hardware
            
        elif INDEX == (2,):
            seltext = mobile
    
        elif INDEX == (3,):
            seltext = wireless
    
        elif INDEX == (6,):
            seltext = AD
        
        elif INDEX == (7,):
            seltext = printers
        print INDEX
        Listbox2.delete(0, TK.END)
        for x in seltext:
            Listbox2.insert(TK.END, x)  

        #Creates List Boxes
    Listbox1 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font, exportselection = 0)
    Listbox1.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
    for x in LocalTemplate:
        Listbox1.insert(TK.END, x)
    Listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", getchoice)
    Listbox2 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font, exportselection = 0)
    Listbox2.grid(column = 4, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
    Listbox2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", getchoice2)
    Listbox3 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font, exportselection = 0)
    Listbox3.grid(column = 6, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, the reason for the error is that self.selection isn't an option, but I am still trying to get the code running smoothly so will probably post a full answer in a day or two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright @Jobes23, This was very fun. Now there were a few 'noobish mistakes' in your code: at the start you had defined `lbl1`, `2`, `3` but instead used `label1`, `2`, `3`, making `lbl1` useless, there were a few unnecessary variables, and added code, also when setting the variables for the listboxes you sometimes used `''`, and others `""` around the words, this doesn't affect the code but it is good to have the same convention throughout your code, it did appear (like Bryan Oakley said) that you had just combined bits and pieces of code from everywhere without regard to how they work alone and together - it is crucial to understand the code to be able to solve problems in it. I have tried to get rid of unnecessary code, but am unsure how much of it you need.

Now I said earlier that `self.selection` wasn't an option, instead I got rid of the `listbox.bind(...)` and made up a button with a command which led to a function which took the selected option and used the result to set the second listbox to a string, which is what you wanted to achieve I think.

```
import Tkinter as TK

class smartstopkiosk_tk(TK.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        #self.parent.title("Smartstop Kiosk")
        software = ('Microsoft', 'Abode', 'SAP', 'Lotus  Notes', 'Jive','Cisco', 'Chrome')
        hardware = ("Computer",  "Charger", " USB Headset", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Webcam")
        microsoft = ("Outlook", "Lync", "Word", "Excel", "PowerPoint", "Visio", "Project", "Publisher")
        adobe = ("Adobe Reader", "Java", "Flash", "Adobe Pro")
        cisco = ('IP Communicator', '')
        wireless = ("MYLOW",  "Corporate", "Visitor", "MYLTW")
        printers  = ("2N", "2S", "3N", "3S", "4N",  "4S",  "5N", "5S")
        mobile =  ("Blackberry", "iPhone","iPad")
        AD  = ("Unlock", "Reset")
        LocalTemplate = ('User Assistance with Software', 'User Assistance with Hardware', 'Mobile Device Support', 'Software Installation Request', 'Hardware Request', 'Wireless Connection', 'Password Reset/Username Unlocked',
    'Add Printer')
        def getchoice2():
            print
            # use same method to find out which of the second list is chosen, and carry on.

        def getchoice():
            seltext = ''
            INDEX = Listbox1.curselection()
            if INDEX == ('0',) or INDEX == ('4',):
                seltext = software
            if INDEX == ('1',) or INDEX == ('5',):
                seltext = hardware
            if INDEX == ('2',):
                seltext = mobile
            if INDEX == ('3',):
                seltext = wireless
            if INDEX == ('6',):
                seltext = AD
            if INDEX == ('7',):
                seltext = printers
            selectchoice.config(command = getchoice2)
            for x in seltext:
                Listbox2.insert(TK.END, x)


        #creates font types
        font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
        font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')
        #Creates Instructions for Users
        stepOne = TK.LabelFrame(self, text=" 1. User Information: ", font = font2)
        stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5,   ipady=5)
        stepTwo = TK.LabelFrame(self, text="2. Select Program or Hardware Problems", font = font2)
        stepTwo.grid(row=3, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        stepThree = TK.LabelFrame(self, text="Please Enter the Problem or Your Request:", font = font2)
        stepThree.grid(row=6, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        #Creates Label for Users
        Label1 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "First Name", font = font)
        Label1.grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
        Label2 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "Last Name", font = font)
        Label2.grid(column = 4, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
        Label3 = TK.Label(stepOne, text = "Mylan UserName", font = font)
        Label3.grid(column = 6, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
        #Creates Entry Box for User input
        self.entry = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
        self.entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1,padx = (10, 10))
        entry2 = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
        entry2.grid(column = 4, row = 1,padx = (10, 10))
        entry3 = TK.Entry(stepOne, width = 30)
        entry3.grid(column = 6, row = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = (10, 10))
        #Creates User Input Box
        Usertext = TK.Text(stepThree, height = 10, width = 110, font = font)
        Usertext.grid(column = 2, row = 15, padx = (10, 10))
        #Creates List Boxes
        Listbox1 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font   = font)
        Listbox1.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
        for i in LocalTemplate:
            Listbox1.insert(TK.END, i)
        Listbox2 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font)
        Listbox2.grid(column = 4, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
        Listbox3 = TK.Listbox(stepTwo, selectmode = 'SINGLE', height = 10, width = 35, font = font)
        Listbox3.grid(column = 6, row = 1, padx = (10, 10))
        #Creates Buttons
        selectchoice = TK.Button(self, text = 'select my choice', font = font2, command = getchoice)
        selectchoice.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))
        Submit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2)
        Submit.grid(column = 3, row = 10, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))
        Startover = TK.Button(self, text = 'Cancel', font = font2)
        Startover.grid(column = 4, row = 10, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

def main():
    app = smartstopkiosk_tk(None)
    app.geometry("1300x768")
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem, though the error message probably told you that:

```
value = widget.get(selection[0])
```

You have no variable named `selection`. Perhaps you meant to use `index[0]` instead of `selection[0]`, since you set `index` on the immediately preceeding line?

Of course, you'll have a similar problem with `widget` which is also undefined.

Comment: @Jobes23: in the version of your code I see now, you have `sender = val.Listbox1`. In this case, `val` is an event object since this is called from the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event handler. The event object does not have a `Listbox1` attribute. Perhaps you meant `self.Listbox1` or `val.widget`. You have other similar errors though, almost as if you're just pasting random code in hopes that it will work. You're using variables that you haven't defined, calling methods on objects that don't have those methods, etc.

Comment: Oh at this point, I was really trying anything to get it to work. It is a bad idea, but if it worked I would be able to go see why it worked.